# Axios POST requests from deployed Azure project failing

Tags: typescript, azure, axios

```
const axiosInstance = axios.create({baseURL: URL,timeout: 5000});

axiosInstance.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = token;

const response = await axiosInstance.post('', body);
```

I try to use a REST API to do some stuff in my local dev environment I can post to the API and get the correct response. The logic is correct and all credentials, keys, scopes and what ever are all set correctly at the right places.

Once I upload the code to Azure and have that particular REST API call triggered, I am left with Bad Request 400 errors

How can I make sure that I can use the REST API on my deployed environment?

I already tried to change the way I set the token in the header while locally I still got my response, deployed, I then received 404.

Using logs I definitely know that my keys scopes and whatever are correct.

Comment: Can you provide some more code on what task your API is performing and what kind of keys and scopes it requires ? -rest api to do some stuff in my local dev environment > What is that some stuff? If you can give me some clarity, It would help.

Comment: i do a post against a third party provider to generate an object. 
i use a token (as auth), a client with id, secret and scope bound to the client id 
i am in touch with said provider and can say that all of these variables are correct
they are also correctly put into keyvault at azure and yaml files
i only replaced existing entries for all but the rest api url as i was updating a running system. all updated entires are correct. the new value is put at all yaml references for .env data